# Team Foundation Server (TFS) proxy - install on Windows XP

Tags: tfs

Can the TFS proxy be installed on Windows XP? I have an environment that I am not allowed to run a Windows Server; however, it is offsite, so a proxy would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that Microsoft changed both their deployment and pricing models from v1.0 of TFS. The proxy requires Windows Server and costs the same as a new instance of TFS.

Answer (score 1):

It was my understanding that the Microsoft TFS Proxy needed to be installed on a Windows Server OS with IIS also installed on the box.  You could of course use a Virtual PC image on your XP machine but I suspect that might go against the same rules that prevent you from running a server on your remote site.

Another alternative is a product called "[Remote Accelerator](http://www.teamprise.com/products/accelerator/)" from Teamprise (who I work for).

http://www.teamprise.com/products/accelerator/

It is designed as a TFS proxy server for single person use, and is designed to work on client OS's such as Windows XP, Vista etc.  Also with a price of $99, it is less expensive than the Microsoft TFS proxy (which has a retail licensing price comparable to another full-blown TFS server instance).